# Elasticsearch 2.x - Return a list of shingles

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, shingles

I have a field  "searchtext" that I have provided a sub-field  "shingle" and I indexing that searchtext field with a shingles filter.

I need to get the list of shingles created for that field so that I can do some operations on that field.  When I retrieve the "searchtext.shingle" field, it just contains the original text.

Does that mean the shingle analyzer that I setup was not working, or that the I need to get the list of shingles back in a different way?

Comment: `provided a sub-field "shingle" ` you mean in the mapping or in the actual json document ? if the former how are you retrieving the searchtext.shingle field in first place ?

Comment: I have a mapping to a property called:  "searchtext"  In my mapping, I created a mapping to "searchtext.shingle" so that I could explicitly retrieve the shingles that are created.  

I normally use the mapping to my document class, but this mapping doesn't exist directly as that field is just created by the mapping that I create.  I want to use the fields to retrieve specific data fields myself rather than use the document mapping as that can get very voluminous  with the amount of data being returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve all the terms of your "shingled" field using the [`_termvectors` endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html) like this:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/your_index/your_type/1/_termvectors?pretty=true' -d '{
  "fields" : ["searchtext.shingle"],
  "offsets" : true,
  "payloads" : true,
  "positions" : true,
  "term_statistics" : true,
  "field_statistics" : true
}'
```

Comment: HI,Thanks for your comment. That is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Val's answer, you can also test how an analyzer is working by using the Analyze API. As an example, let's build a custom analyzer and then test what tokens it produces for a given input

```
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
var defaultIndex = "analyzer-test";
var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);

var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

if (client.IndexExists(defaultIndex).Exists)
    client.DeleteIndex(defaultIndex);

client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex, c => c
    .Settings(s => s
        .Analysis(a => a
            .TokenFilters(tf => tf
                .Shingle("my_shingle", sh => sh
                    .MaxShingleSize(3)
                    .OutputUnigrams()
                )
            )
            .Analyzers(an => an
                .Custom("my_shingle_analyzer", sa => sa
                    .Tokenizer("standard")
                    .Filters("lowercase", "my_shingle")
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Now to test it

```
var analysisResponse = client.Analyze(a => a
    .Index(defaultIndex)
    .Analyzer("my_shingle_analyzer")
    .Text("This is the text I want to analyze")
);

foreach (var token in analysisResponse.Tokens)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{token.Token}");
}
```

emits the following tokens

```
this
this is
this is the
is
is the
is the text
the
the text
the text i
text
text i
text i want
i
i want
i want to
want
want to
want to analyze
to
to analyze
analyze
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had tested the analyzer using JSON directly, but thinks for the .NET code!